# Offline map using osmdroid does not move to location

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) v.3.0.9 to implement an offline map in my application. I am animating the map to a particular position (latitute, longitude).
The following is the code I am using:

```
mapView.animateTo(new GeoPoint(lat, long));
mapView.zoomToSpan(lat1 - lat2, long1 - long2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZoomToSpan seems not to be working in Osmdroid use the following code may be it will help you.

```
mapControl = mapView.getController();
        mapControl.setZoom(15);
        mapControl.setCenter(new GeoPoint((maxLatitude + minLatitude) / 2,
                (maxLongitude + minLongitude) / 2));
```